# how to sort column by descending and match pairs on another column on mysql

Tags: mysql

I don't think I even phrase it right, but I'll display the table before and after the sort.

Before Sort:

```
___________________
|  NAME   |  AGE   |
|==================|
| Ace     |   23   |
| May     |   15   |
| Ann     |   21   |
| May     |   38   |
| Ace     |   77   |
| Ann     |   35   |
|==================|
```

After Sort:

```
 ___________________
|  NAME   |  AGE   |
|==================|
| Ace     |   77   |
| Ace     |   23   |
| May     |   38   |
| May     |   15   |
| Ann     |   35   |
| Ann     |   21   |
|==================|
```

So, as you can see I am sorting by age in descending order but, it will pair up the ones with the same Name together.  How would I do this in MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: A table isn't really a table unless it has a PRIMARY KEY. What's yours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to join in the table with the max age.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select name, max(age) as maxage
      from t
      group by name
     ) tsum
     on tsum.name = t.name
order by tsum.maxage desc, t.name, t.age desc;
```

EDIT:

I think the answer to your question is putting `t.age desc` in the `order by` clause.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac9c5/2) is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates the code.

As for your second question, the `where` clause would go right before the `order by`.

Comment: It is one table. SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY NAME ASC,AGE DESC will do same thing without join

Comment: @bksi . . . No it won't.  The names are not ordered alphabetically, they are ordered by the maximum age in the table.

Comment: It almost worked, the results for "May" the age part are in the wrong order. It show 15, then 38. The others on the list are fine.
I also added names without repeats  in seems to throw others that are in order before out of order.

Also if I were to throw in a WHERE clause, I put it before the ORDER BY?